# read csv file in q kdb without specifying the column type manually

Tags: kdb

In there any way is kdb to read a csv file which is as simple as read_csv() function in pandas.

I usually use something like below code to read a csv in kdb

```
("I*FS";enlist ",")0:`:a.csv / where a.csv is a csv file with Integer, String, Float and Symbol columns
```

Many times in practical cases, the csv file we want to read has more than 100 columns, then it is difficult to provide the column types to function.
Is there a way in kdb to read csv where kdb can understand the type of column by itself?
something like

```
("*";enlist ",")0:`:a.csv / this fails
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simon Garland wrote a "csv guess" script many years ago: https://github.com/simongarland/csvguess

It might still be relevant. Some IDEs (such as qStudio and Kx's analyst(?)) I believe also have this functionality built in.

Alternatively you could read the first line of the csv to get the number of columns (say `n`) and then `n#"*"` to read the entire csv as string columns:

```
q)(count["," vs first system"head -1 a.csv"]#"*";enlist ",")0:`:a.csv
col1 col2 col3
----------------------
,"a" ,"1" "2019-01-01"
,"b" ,"2" "2019-01-01"
,"c" ,"3" "2019-01-01"
```

Comment: Windows doesn't have the head command, so the following is a pure q solution to reading in the column names, which could be adjusted for reading in the first n columns
```(enlist "c";enlist 1) 1: r til -1 + first where "\n"=r:read1(`:parameters.csv;0;100000000)```